# Why my log is not align with my text on the header?

Tags: html, css, header

I was trying to make my header, pretty simple just a logo and some text. But I can't align my text with my image. Does anyone know why this happens and how I could solve this problem?

This is my code.

```css
header {
    background-color:lightblue;
}

.nav-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 940px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto auto 0;
}

.logo-header {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
}

.header-text { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
}

.welcome-msg {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: gray;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0.1px; 
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #000;
    padding: 0.5px; 
}
```

```html
    <header>  
    <div class="nav-box">
        <img class="logo-header" src="C:\Users\gusta\OneDrive\Desktop\Programação\to-do\ToDo\tasks\templates\images\logo\logo_transparent.png">
        <div class="header-text">
            <h2 class="welcome-msg">Welcome to Tasks to be Done!</h2> 
            <p  class="welcome-msg">Put your tasks right bellow, </p>
            <p  class="welcome-msg">press start in the tracker button and let´s do it! </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

[`This is what shows up on my page`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moaEQ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did this in my editor. Should get you what you want.

```
 `.nav-box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto auto 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.logo-header {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: auto;
    bottom: auto;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 2em;
    padding: 1em;
}

.header-text {
    /* removed styling */
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your imagine tag inside the div where your text is and remove all align things from your image and your text, so everything will be aligned together when you make changes in your div class.

Case you change your mind about setting the logo and text one above the other and want then side by side you can use the attribute display: flex; that will make the items only take space that they need to fit it in the page and they can sit side by side of each other.